# Create Captch Component in Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex3

Please Any body tell me How to do Captch in Flex?

This type of Captch Creation needed any Java Services?

Could you give some example How to do Captch in Flex?(Just want 4 Word Text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that spambots are not so clever to interfere with flex app,
 so if you want to check code at client side, 
you can create text component with random text and (if you feel paranoid about bots that capture images and recognize text on them) apply some standard filters like blur, dropshadow and so on.

Alternatively you can create something like mx:HTML and then use some captcha service, like one you can see on following page: http://bash.im/add .